# Plotting Day of Year Data in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having some trouble getting the X-Axis to correctly plot the "Day of Year" the data comes in, but it seems to plot the "time" instead.

```
Time_Plot <- Glass_DB %>%
  mutate(`Date & Time In Hour` = yday(`Date & Time In Hour`)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = `Date & Time In Hour`)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 50, colour = "white", fill = "#1380A1") + 
  labs(title = "Glass Category Orders",
       subtitle = "Jobs by Day of Year") + 
  scale_x_time() + bbc_style()
Time_Plot
```

[image]

Sample Dataset:

```
 structure(c(1554973200, 1554811200, 1554811200, 1554811200, 1554793200, 
1554732000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")

Date & Time In Hour
3/23/2019 11:00
3/7/2019 16:00
2/25/2019 13:00
3/27/2019 13:00
3/28/2019 11:00
3/13/2019 8:00
3/8/2019 9:00
3/20/2019 13:00
3/29/2019 10:00
3/12/2019 15:00
4/1/2019 10:00
```

Update:--------------------------------------------------

Removed `scale_x_time()` to correct the time issue. Is there a way to show months in the X-axis to make the graph more readable.

[image]

Comment: Sharing sample data with `dput` is a preferred way to share data

Comment: You don't want the x-axis to be time, so delete `scale_x_time()` from your plot. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Thank you @Gregor, that solved the time issue. It now shows the "Day" by number. Is there a way to change that to month or a more readable way?

Comment: I mean, you're using `yday` which returns an integer. If you don't want an integer on the x-axis, don't use `yday`. Just delete your `mutate` line and put the datetime-classed variable on the x-axis. Since it is a datetime, using `scale_x_datetime` is appropriate (`datetime`, not just `time`) and will be used by default. The default will probably be good, but you can customize it, see the help page for example `?scale_x_datetime`.

Comment: If you'd like to stay with your original approach you could also specify your breaks manually and label them `scale_x_continuous(breaks=cumsum(c(1,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30)),
                     labels =c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec") )`

Comment: @TobiO (a) if you're going to do that terrible thing, at least use the built-in var `labels = month.abb` rather than typing out all the months. But (b), why? Why would you take a nicely formatted datetime for which the defaults work well, change it into an integer, and then do extra work to label the integer as if it were a datetime??

Comment: @Gregor because learning how to make a custom scale helped me to understand ggplot better. As I said "if you want to stay with your original approach". And I learned now, that there is something like `letters`/`LETTERS` for month :-)
Also I'm not sure, if switching to month on the x-axis would not also change the bin size. Although of course I don't know, why there should be 50 bins in this data... (one bin per 2 days?)